# What is this duapp mirror of Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, copycat-sites, phishing

While googling for a question that I saw a few days ago on Stack Overflow, I stumbled upon a copy of the question on this website (Google took me there):

http://stackoverflow.duapp.com/

What on Earth is this and is it dangerous?

**Edit:** Ok, thank you for the link, reported there as described; but let's have this question open just in case someone happens to know what this site is. To me, it stands out because it looks like an exact copy of the real site.

Comment: OK, great link, reported there! Still let's have the question open, maybe someone knows what it actually is about.

Comment: Why downvote when we all ought to be happy this got reported? Just closing as duplicate is enough - we don't want to send a message that this is somehow bad behavior, do we?